# "Ask Question" retrieving the last question asked

Tags: bug, asking-questions

I clicked on **Ask Question** today, it took me to the right place to post my question but with my previous question's data already there in the Title text box as well as Body text box, you can see in the following screenshot:

[image]

I was afraid that it will update my last question asked, so I skipped it. I think it's very rare but I found it today.

Comment: I undeleted this post because I think it may be helpful to future visitors, if they have the same experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the last question asked at the time was somehow saved as a draft and I was unaware of it because it was posted successfully. Later, I discarded it and never saw it again on clicking **Ask Question**. But earlier, it created little bit confusion.